# Why does another computers wallpaper change if I change mine? Windows 11

Tags: windows-11

On Windows 10 it was easy to disable theme sync in the settings, but now with the update to Windows 11 it isn't as simple. How do I disable desktop wallpaper sync now?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I disable desktop wallpaper sync now?

Windows 11 syncs settings via your Microsoft Account and One Drive.

[Sync Windows settings](https://www.whynotwin11.com/how-do-i-sync-my-settings-in-windows-11/)

You need to refer to the section near the end here (C)  on customizing individual settings.

> **(A)** How to Customize Sync Settings on Windows 11 Before you can play with
> sync settings on your Windows 11, you have to login to Windows 11
> through your Microsoft Account. Its because Windows 11 synchronization
> is carried out through OneDrive.
>
> **(B)** Access Sync Settings on Windows 11 Open Start Menu Now Click Settings
> Than Click Accounts Click Sync your Settings On the right fringe. Sync
> your Settings in front you now. Set On and Off Synchronization on
> Windows 11 Go to the Sync your Settings like steps above. The first
> section is Sync Settings. Now you can see one option under this
> section which reads as Sync your settings on This PC. If you move the
> slider to the right then it will turn on. And if you move it to the
> left then it will be set to off.
>
> **(C)** Set Individual Sync Settings on Windows 11 You can set individual
> settings for all the categories to ON or OFF like Theme, Internet
> Explorer Settings, Password, Language Preferences, Ease of Access, and
> Other Windows Settings